# How to avoid cells background image from hiding the separator line between rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view I am using custom image for the UITableView cell's background. It works perfectly except for the fact it hides the row separator. And now there is no row visible.

Is there a way to increase the distance so that cells will get separated.

Please help!!!

Thanks,

Comment: can u share the screen-shot of table view

Comment: a question is without some code and needs a picture

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you are seeing, it's a bit hard to tell. That said, you could try adding the separator to the image so that it shows up in the cell.

If you want to change the height of the cell, implement the -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method in the table view delegate. Just return the correct height for the row at indexPath. I believe there is also a way to set the rowHeight in the table view properties in interface builder if all cells will be the same, but I tend to stay away from IB when possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge you can add a line  image to the cell as a footer.So that you can see the separator

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to override the `-setFrame:` method in your custom cell and return the same frame with height minus 1 pixel.

Also be sure to call `[super layoutSubviews];` in your `-layoutSubviews` method *if you have overridden this method* with some custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

LineSeparator may be invisible to you because of your background image in your cell. Try to change the style of your separator.

**Alternative Way:**

Otherwise You have to **add a one pixel line** to the bottom of your Custom cell background image by your **designer** and if it's still not visible in your `tableView`, then you have to increase a height for your cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view if you have one that is inside your Cell is exactly the same size as your cell's size.

Make sure:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is setting your cell heights correctly for all cells.